# Play console not showing statics for managed app

Tags: android, statistics, google-play, release, emm

The Play console is not showing the statistics of the app installed on the client side as they are using the SOTI Mobility Control as EMM for managing their device. The statics are showing only the count of device that we installed in our dev environment. As we are not getting any statistics of the client side installation counts.

We want to get the statistics of the app usage in the client side in the Google play console.